# ソースコードの変更履歴管理を行う管理システムのコマンドラインツール

Tags: linux

**質問内容：開発者がソースコードの変更履歴管理を行う管理システムは多数ありますが、それには対応したクライアントが必要です。Linux向けで使用できる有名なコマンドラインツールを1つあげてください。**

大学の問題で出されている問題なのですが、自分で調べてみても全くわかりません。まず問題の解釈が分からず、ITのスペシャリストの方々にご教授いただけると幸いです。

コマンドラインツール等も調べたのですが、いまいち何を指しているのかがよくわかっていません。
単純に、Gitという回答なんでしょうか？
質問の意図や、それに対応する回答をご教授いただけますと幸いです。

Comment: この問題文に含まれている言葉を全てひとつずつ解説していると、回答がとても長くなってしまいそうです。単に「分からない」だけでなく、ご自身で「Git」というところに辿り着くまでの思考の過程を問題を [edit] して追記いただけないでしょうか。そうすることで、どこまで分かっていてどこから分かっていないのかを明らかにしたいです。

Comment: "出題の意図" は出題者本人にしか分かりえないので、第三者に質問しても結局はあなたと同じ立場で回答を推測することしかできないと思います。 / 提示された情報の範囲であれば Git も一つの回答だと思いますが、質問に対して不明な点があるのなら、質問者本人に尋ねることをまずは優先すべきだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

問題文を最初から見ていきます。

> 開発者がソースコードの変更履歴管理を行う管理システムは多数ありますが、それには対応したクライアントが必要です。Linux向けで使用できる有名なコマンドラインツールを1つあげてください

最初に引っかかるのは

> ソースコードの変更履歴管理を行う管理システム

でしょうか？　でしたら、お好みのWeb検索エンジンで上記のキーワードを検索してみましょう。
こういった管理システムの総称を知ることが出来るはずです。

では、問題文の前段を最初から読み直してみます。

> 開発者がソースコードの変更履歴管理を行う管理システムは**多数あります**が、それには**対応したクライアントが必要**です。

先程、Web検索をしたのなら、いくつかの管理システムの名前が目に入ったと思います。
それらのシステムを使用するためには対応したクライアントが必要なようです。

もし**クライアント**が何を指すのかが分からなければ、Web検索してみましょう。
weblio辞書とかe-Words、Wikipediaなどで説明されています。
**こういう感じのものなのか**というふわっとした理解でも今は十分です。

では、問題文の後段へ入っていきます。

> Linux向けで使用できる**有名な**コマンドラインツールを1つあげてください。

最初に解釈に困るのは強調した部分かと思いますが、直後の**コマンドラインツール**も聞き慣れない言葉かもしれません。
分からない言葉が出てきたらWeb検索してみましょう。……何となく理解できたでしょうか？

さて、少し問題文から話がそれます。
そもそもWeb検索エンジンの検索結果は**基本的には**よく閲覧されるページや人気があるページが上位に来ます。
言い換えると、(キーワードを間違えなければ)**検索結果の最初の方は有名なページ**です。

上記を踏まえて最初に検索した**ソースコードの変更履歴管理を行う管理システムの総称**と**linux**をキーワードにしてWeb検索してみます。
いくつかの管理システムの名前が目に入るはずです。**それらは全て有名だと考えてよいと思います。**

あとは**その管理システムの名前**と**使い方**辺りをキーワードにしてWeb検索をすれば問題文への答えが得られるはずです。

最後に、問題文の意図は出題した方ではないので分かりかねますが、**こういう管理システムがあってこういう風に利用するんだ**ということを理解して欲しいのかな？と個人的に感じました。